# What can I do to get Google, Facebook, Microsoft, and Twitter out of my Life as Much as Possible?

Tags: defense, surveillance

Now that those four are in the censorship business and cooperate to surveil and exclude, I want to do more to get them out of my life.

No Facebook, no Twitter, no YouTube, no G-mail, no Microsoft, no Skype--check.

Mostly use the TOR network and TAILS--check.

Use Fedora with ProtonVPN with AES-256 in GCM/SHA-512 and add-ons (1) uBlock Origin (2) Privacy Badger (3) NoScript (4) TrackMeNot (5) Fingerprint Defender (6) HTTPS Everywhere (7) Multi-Account containers.

I am also very interested in protecting my family.

What more can I do to limit their surveillance and control?  What active steps can I take to mess up their surveillance?